# How can I automize finding if values of a list exist in another column dataframe in R

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, if-statement, bioinformatics

In the existing csv there is a column that contains one of the following codes i.e. outer membrane [GO:0019867] for every row. I want to add a column to the csv that will give a category to every row i.e. OuterMembrane. So I have add an empty column and I thought of making this list in order to automatically when a code is referred to the csv, the general category will be added. (not all coding included)

```
categ <- list(OuterMembrane = c("outer membrane [GO:0019867]","cell outer membrane [GO:0009279]", "integral component of membrane [GO:0016021]", "membrane [GO:0016020]"),
              Cytoplasmic =c("ribosome [GO:0005840]", "cytoplasm [GO:0005737]"),
              Extracellular=c(),
              InnerMembrane=c("plasma membrane [GO:0005886]", "membrane [GO:0016020]"),
              Periplasmic=c("periplasmic space [GO:0042597]"),
              CellWall=c(),
              Vacuole=c(),
              Lipoproteins=c())


csv1 <- csv1%>%
  add_column("Subcellular Localization" = NA)

for (row in (categ)){ 
   if row(categ) %in% csv1{
```

..................?????????

Comment: Hi! If I am understaning right  what you are trying to do is to create a new column to your dataframe based on the content of another column. And you tried to summarize the new_column_content - existing_column_content pairs in a list. Do I understand it correctly? Can you describe the output you want?

Comment: Yes, exactly! So I want any of the codes in brankets to be searched in the dataframe, and the name of the category to which it belongs to be added. The output will be a new column (Subcellular Localization) in the csv1 that will have one of the values OuterMembrane, Cytoplasmic, Extracellular etc. in each row. The previous column is named Cellular component and contains one or two of the codes in brankets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `for loop` could be of help to your problem.

```
csv1['subcellular_localization'] <- NA      #add a new column 

for (i in 1:nrow(csv1)) {                   #fill in the new column
  for (j in 1:length(categ)) {
    if (csv1$cell_comp[i] %in% categ[[j]]) {
       csv1$subcellular_localization[i] <- names(categ[j])
    }
  }
}

csv1
```

Input:

```
> csv1
  name                      cell_comp
1   p1    outer membrane [GO:0019867]
2   p2         cytoplasm [GO:0005737]
3   p3 periplasmic space [GO:0042597]
```

Output:

```
> csv1
  name                      cell_comp subcellular_localization
1   p1    outer membrane [GO:0019867]            OuterMembrane
2   p2         cytoplasm [GO:0005737]              Cytoplasmic
3   p3 periplasmic space [GO:0042597]              Periplasmic
```

**EDIT**

In case there more than one cellular components per protein, the following form the for loop can be used (using the `stringr` library):

```
library(stringr)

for (i in 1:nrow(csv1)) {
  components <- unlist(strsplit(csv1$cell_comp[i], ';'))
  for (component in components) {
    component <- str_trim(component, side='left')
    for (j in 1:length(categ)) {
      if (component %in% categ[[j]]) {
        if (is.na(csv1$subcellular_localization[i])) {
          csv1$subcellular_localization[i] <- names(categ[j])
        } else {
          if (csv1$subcellular_localization[i] != names(categ[j])) {
            csv1$subcellular_localization[i] <- paste(csv1$subcellular_localization[i],names(categ[j]), sep="; ")
          } else {
            csv1$subcellular_localization[i] <- names(categ[j])
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Input*:

```
> csv1
  name                                                                cell_comp
1   p1 outer membrane [GO:0019867]; integral component of membrane [GO:0016021]
2   p2                   cytoplasm [GO:0005737]; periplasmic space [GO:0042597]
3   p3                                           periplasmic space [GO:0042597]
```

Output*:

```
> csv1
  name                                                                cell_comp subcellular_localization
1   p1 outer membrane [GO:0019867]; integral component of membrane [GO:0016021]            OuterMembrane
2   p2                   cytoplasm [GO:0005737]; periplasmic space [GO:0042597] Cytoplasmic; Periplasmic
3   p3                                           periplasmic space [GO:0042597]              Periplasmic
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **intersect** function in the R package called **dplyr** which is something that you can use in finding common elements between different columns, different lists etc. Its worth checking out.
For example, you can read the columns as vectors and then perform the following: 
column1 = c(1,2,3,4)
column2 = c(6,5,4,3,2) 
 
intersect(vector_1, vector_2) 
Now this will return 3 and 4 as they are common in both the columns.